# Why does the LIBRARY_PATH variable redundantly use "/../../" for locating certain directories?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld

I was analyzing `gcc -v main.c -Wl, --verbose`, when I realized a few of the paths mentioned in the `LIBRARY_PATH` variable were laughably redundant (assuming `../` refers to the parent directory).

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

For example, look at this:
`:/usr/lib/../lib/`
Why would this exist? What's the point of going into `lib`, then coming out of it and again going back into? Given that `/usr/lib` is also included at the end.

Comment: It's probably just an artifact.  It's possible the entry was constructed from one or more variables that could also be empty, in which case it would have resolved to just "../lib".  The path would first be normalized prior to use, so there is no "going in and out of" any extra directories.

Comment: I could also be the result of defective config scripting somewhere.

Comment: I think that it's fine as is. The path will get resolved regardless, but now it's much clearer how the path was constructed. This way, any build error is probably better understood than when the build environment would normalise the paths.

Comment: I like especially "/lib/../lib/" - it's palindrome!